# AWS lambda set function access policy programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lambda-authorizer, aws-policies

I am trying to set user specific lambda policies using [this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Authorizing.IAM.LambdaCreatePolicy.html). Can someone tell me why this resource specification to access only a single lambda is wrong?

```
resource = "arn:aws:region:*:*:function:orderinputapi-alpha-writeMe";
```

when I use:

```
resource="*"
```

it works perfectly (the user has full access to all lambdas), but when I try to restrict access to only allow a single lambda function I get "user is not authorized to access the resource" when I try to access it. I confirmed the function is the exact name of the lambda.

The full policy statement being created by my code is:

```
{ Action: 'execute-api:Invoke',
Effect: 'Allow',
Resource:'arn:aws:region:*:*:function:orderinputapi-alpha-writeMe' }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error with your ARN:
Instead of `arn:aws:region:*:*:function:orderinputapi-alpha-writeMe`, it should be `arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:orderinputapi-alpha-writeMe`

Also, if you setting the permissions for the same region and account, you can simply drop `*` so the ARN would be:

`arn:aws:lambda:::function:orderinputapi-alpha-writeMe`